# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME top bar menus broken

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

So my laptop crashed during a set of live updates, and now the top right context menu looks like this:

[image]

It's missing icons, and none of the buttons are functional.

Additionally, the middle menu can no longer clear context items:

[image]

The rest of the desktop seems ok.

I've had a brief google and tried a few things:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

Without any success. Has anyone run across this problem before?

Comment: Same issues after changing the theme.

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell` didn't fix the issue either I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure what I did to cause the error. I was running live patch on battery power a few days ago. I have a faulty battery which caused my system to shutdown, on reboot my menus were like this. I waited a couple of days and occasionally tried a few fixes to no avail!

Comment: `No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:6839): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:02:09.716: cannot open display: :0
`

Comment: are you on wayland session?

Comment: Turning off the wayland session fixed the issues! Thank you for suggesting it!